# Macro for scheme like function in clojure

Tags: clojure, macros, scheme

I want to create scheme like define macro, here is my try:

```
(defmacro define [list & body] 
    `(defn ,(first list) [~@(rest list)] ~body))
```

but when I run:

(define (foo a b) (+ a b))

I've got error: `java.lang.Exception: First argument to def must be a Symbol (NO_SOURCE_FILE:18)`

what's wrong with my macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `~` to unquote the symbol name:

```
(defmacro define [list & body]
  `(defn ~(first list) [~@(rest list)] ~@body))
```